# Does E language support multiple inheritance?

Tags: specman, e

I would like to build a new struct that inherits from other multiple structs, something like that:

```
struct new_struct like struct_a, struct_b, struct_c is {
    // The new_struct supposed to have all the fields of struct a/b/c
};
```

Is there a way to inherit from multiple structs in E?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no multiple inheritance in e. However, not long ago interfaces were added, this is probably the closest thing.

What is exactly your purpose? In some cases 'struct_member' macro or when subtype can do a job expected from multiple inheritance.